# failed to upgrade to 12.04, stuck at 11.10

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, upgrade

So my Problem occurs as i already mentioned in my title after i tried to upgrad my old version. For no reason the upgrade broke of after the installation. Now i am not able to upgrade anything the upgrade manager is always closing when i am trying to open it.

Hope you guys can help,

with kind regards

Comment: Sounds like you might have to bite the bullet and just reinstall and start fresh.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to fix it but it will be slower and crash more often. The best thing is just to make a solid backup of all your files and start over with a fresh 12.04.

I had the same issue when upgrading to 11.10, I fixed it but it wasn't as good as a fresh 11.10

Linked question:

- [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6328/10698)

Answer (score 2):

Open up a Terminal

write

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

if that fails try

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Also check if your sources.list is set to precise instead of oneiric at the end of each deb and deb-src line.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```